# Javascript push a promise into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, es6-promise

I'm trying to create an array of promises and call them with `Promise.all`.

I'm having trouble with correctly pushing the functions into the array, it seems they are being called instead of inserted and wait for `Promise.all()`.

```
function findSpecialAbility(players, gameId, message) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let playersWithSpecials = _.reject(players, function(p) {
      return p.role === 'alphaWolf' ||
        p.role === 'betaWolf' ||
        p.role === 'villager' ||
        p.role === 'alchemist' ||
        p.targetId === 0 ||
        p.abilityUsed === true;
    });
    if (playersWithSpecials.length === 0) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      let specialsToUse = [];
      for (let i = 0, j = playersWithSpecials.length; i < j; i++) {
        specialsToUse.push(useSpecialAbility(playersWithSpecials[i], gameId, message, players));
      }
      //Promise.all(specialsToUse).then(r = > console.log(r));
    }
  });
}


// Using promise below because some of the role will have database updates.
function useSpecialAbility(playerData, gameId, message, players) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (playerData.role === 'seer') {
      let getTargetData = _.find(players, {
        id: playerData.targetId
      });
      message.guild.members.get(playerData.id).send(`Your target is a ${getTargetData.role}!`);
      resolve('foo');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Well.. you're Invoking the function when you try to add it to your array. Hint: as soon as you open that constructor it'll run.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the issue I just don't know how to get around it...

Comment: You can use objects, pass in the function without constructor and execute it in useSpecialAbility.

Comment: Would still have a flow control issue,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> it seems they are being called instead of inserted and wait for `Promise.all()`

It seems like you want the code inside the promises to simultaneously run when you call `Promise.all`.

If that is what you want then wrapping code in the promises is probably not what you want.

---

Instead you need to wrap the code you want to run later in just a plain ole function. You can add those functions to an array and then call each one in a loop. And by the looks of your code, you probably don't even need to promises.

See the example below:

```js
// this function returns another function `runnable` and can be called later (synchronously) to get the result
function runLater (index) {
  return function runnable() {
    console.log(`this code is ran later. from ${index}`);
    return `from ${index}`;
  }
}

console.log('this is run now');

const tasks = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  tasks.push(runLater(i));
}

console.log('this is run');


// use Array.prototype.map to map the array of functions to what they return by invoking each one.
const valuesOfTasks = tasks.map(task => task());
console.log({valuesOfTasks});

console.log('this is run after');
```

---

You only need promises when you're dealing with async control flow. Delaying execution can be done synchronously, just by wrapping a section of code in a function. When you want to execute that code, just invoke the function.

Edit:

> I need to wait for all the useSpecialAbility to be done before moving on with my code. Some of them will write/read from the database, that's why I used promises.

In that case you will have to use `Promise.all` but you'll still need to wrap those promises in functions with no arguments if you want them to all run at the same time.

---

The code block of promises is actually ran synchronously (vs running the block when you call `.then` or `Promise.all`) so if you still want the promises run later, you can still just wrap them in functions.

See this example:

```js
function waitThenSay(milliseconds, message) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(`waiting to say: "${message}"...`)
    setTimeout(() => {
      // log to console for immediate side-effect
      console.log(message.toUpperCase() + '!');
      // also resolve with the message
      resolve(message);
    }, milliseconds);
  });
}

console.log('this is run first');

// tasks is an array of functions that return promises
const tasks = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i += 1) {
  tasks.push(() => waitThenSay(i * 2000, `hello from task ${i}`));
}

console.log('this is run second');

// execute the tasks by mapping each function to their invocation
const arrayOfPromises = tasks.map(task => task())

// call Promise.all on that array
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(result => {
  console.log({result});
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need to wait for all the `useSpecialAbility` to be done before moving on with my code. Some of them will write/read from the database, that's why I used promises.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a fairly straightforward async/await approach for pushing promises to an array and using Promise.all on them thereafter.

```
async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const promises = [];
        
        //Conditionally add promises to the promises array

        if(req.user.hobby === "Hockey")
            promises.push(() => Hobby.find({name: "Hockey"}));

        else
            promises.push(() => Hobby.find({}));

        if(req.user.country === "Canada")
            promises.push(() => User.find({country: "Canada"}));
        
        //Execute the promises in Promise.all()            
                
        const docs = await Promise.all(promises.map(promise => promise()));
    
        if(docs.length === 0){
            var err = new Error('No documents found');
            err.status = 404;
            return next(err);
        }        

        if(docs[1])
            console.log(docs[1]); //array of User docs with country field value set to Canada
    
        console.log(docs[0]); //array of all hobbys or only hobbys with the name field set to Hockey

        res.json(docs);
    }
    catch(err){
        return next(err);
    }
}
```